# Jquery : Product between 2 lists of inputs into a 3rd list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have much experience in jQuery, I'm facing the following challenge

I have the following table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Total Price</td>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="itemRow">
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="unitPrice"/>/td>
            <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice"/></td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" name="total"/>
```

Additionally, I'm able to clone #itemRow as many times as required, enlarging the amount of items.

The idea is to calculate the total price for each row (by `quantity` * `unitPrice`) and assign it to `totalPrice`. And assign the sum of `totalPrice` to `total`.

This is the javascript I'm using, but I get an error that says "cantidades[i].val() is not a function"

```
function calculate(){

    var $total = $('#total');

    var $cantidades = $('input[name=quantity]')
    var $unitarios  = $('input[name=unitPrice]')
    var $totales = $('input[name=totalPrice]')

    var len = $cantidades.length;

    $total.val(0);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        // calculate total for the row. ERROR HERE!
        $totales[i].val($cantidades[i].val() * $unitarios[i].val());

        // Accumulate total  
        $total.val($totalExento.val() + $totales[i].val());
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I think I'm not getting "jQuery objects" from the selector but I'm not sure hot to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $cantidades[i] would actually give you the javascript object. You should use $cantidades[i].value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `var $cantidades = $('input[name=quantity]')` retrieves a jQuery instance that cannot be accessed like you did with `$cantidades[i]`.

Fix it like this:

```
var singleElementCantidades = $($cantidades[i]);
singleElementCantidades.val();
```

What happened is that `$('input[name=quantity]')` retrieves an array that is an instance of jQuery. And when you access its content by using cantidades[i] you are not managing a jQuery instance anymore, you are accessing something else wich doesn't have the definition of val.

Comment: In fact this selector retrieves all the instances of that field and works as expected, but when I iterate them, the [i] element does not have all the jQuery methods thatI expected, including 'val()'

Comment: my second suggestion should fix your problem. if it does, tell me so i can explain you why

Comment: Thank you so much, I was breaking my head trying to understand why I was not able to use jQuery methods. Worked perfectly

Comment: you learned it the hardway ahahhah but you will remember for ever! =)

Answer (score 1):

$cantidades would give you a `jquery` object however by using `index` or '`get`' property would actually give you the equivalent `javascript` object. So in your case, you would need to use `$cantidades[i].value.` instead of `$cantidades[i].val()`.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        $totales[i].value = $cantidades[i].value * $unitarios[i].value;
        $total.val($totalExento.val() + $totales[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: Upvote because this also works as plain js instead of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot globally get $('input[name=quantity]'), $('input[name=unitPrice]') and $('input[name=totalPrice]').

You should identify them for each row.

Here a example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83j0ua7d/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Total Price</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="unitPrice"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="totalPrice"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="addRow">addRow</button>
<button type="button" id="calculate">calculate</button>
<input type="number" name="total" id="total"/>
```

The js part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $total = $('#total');
  var $addRow = $('#addRow');
  var $calculate = $('#calculate');

  var $emptyRow = $('tbody tr').clone();
  var $body = $('tbody');

  $addRow.on('click', function () {
    $body.append($emptyRow.clone());
  });

  $calculate.on('click', function () {
    var total = 0;

    $body.find('tr').each(function () {
      var $row = $(this);
      var q = Number($row.find('[name=quantity]').val());
      var p = Number($row.find('[name=unitPrice]').val());
      var subTotal = q * p;

      $row.find('[name=totalPrice]').val(subTotal)
      total += subTotal;
    });

    $total.val(total);
  })

});
```

Comment: The selectors work perfectly, they get all the inputs I need to iterate. The problem was the iteration itself. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Hmmm, I also change the way to access of all inputs. Otherwise, in my opinion I would get the input like this $('[name=quantity]:eq(' + i + ')'), not $($cantidades[i]). It makes the code more clearer, because you already got and jquery object, so why recreate another object? See the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/83j0ua7d/1/